# How to implement external filter in angular ui-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express, angular-ui-grid

I have an application in Angular. In application using ui-grid and want to do filters to every column.
I already did a search for the whole table, and it's work. There is my html:

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="FlatController as flat">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="flat.searchText" ng-change="flat.refreshData()" placeholder="Search...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-wrapper">
        <div ui-grid="flat.gridOptions" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-auto-resize id="grid1" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's my controller:

```
angular.module('flatCtrl', ['flatService', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select', 'ui.date'])
        .controller('FlatController', ['Flat', 'socketio', '$filter', function(Flat, socketio, $filter){

            vm = this;
            Flat.allFlat()
                .success(function(data){
                    vm.flats = data;
                    vm.gridOptions = {
                        data: data,
                         columnDefs: [
                            {field: 'id', displayName: 'Id', visible: false},
                            {field: 'creator', displayName: 'Creator', visible: false},
                            {field: 'typelocal', displayName: 'Typ lokalu', visible: true},
                            {field: 'country', displayName: 'Kraj', visible: true},
                            {field: 'city', displayName: 'Miejscowość', visible: true},
                            {field: 'district', displayName: 'Dzielnica', visible: true}
                         ]
                    };
                    vm.refreshData = function() {
                        vm.gridOptions.data = $filter('filter')(vm.flats, vm.searchText, undefined);
                    };
    });
```

Maybe who knows how to add inputs in my html for every ui-grid column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `registerRowsProcessor`.

They actually have an example in the [website](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20321%20Single%20filter). Please take a look.

Comment: I'm try to use this, but have an error here: $scope.filter = function() {    $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh(); };    grid was undefined(

Comment: Please add 
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
},
inside your gridOptions

Comment: of course, using it inside: $scope.gridOptions = {data: data, enableSorting: true, enableFiltering: false, onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
                        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                        $scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor( vm.singleFilter, 200 );
                    },
                     enableColumnResizing: true};

Comment: anyway i can filter the rendered values and not the entity itself ? ex: after applying a date filter